# Horizontal scroll add class when scrolled to end and beginning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a horizontal scrolling div that, when scrolled, I want to add classes on its' parent #container div (with jQuery preferably).

If the div hasn't yet been scrolled:

```
$('#container').addClass('shadow-right').removeClass('shadow-left');
```

If the div isn't at the beginning or the end:

```
$('#container').addClass('shadow-right shadow-left');
```

and if the container is scrolled all the way to the end:

```
$('#container').addClass('shadow-left').removeClass('shadow-right');
```

I've set up a JSFiddle with some basic html/css explaining what I'm trying to accomplish:

http://jsfiddle.net/Y39z8/3/

I'd appreciate any help I can get.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### [See this working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/Y39z8/9/)

Here's the jQuery involved:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#scroll-container").on("scroll", function () {
        var cur = $(this).scrollLeft();
        if (cur == 0) {
            $('#container').addClass('shadow-right').removeClass('shadow-left');
        } 
        else {
            var max = $(this)[0].scrollWidth - $(this).parent().width();
            if (cur == max) {
                $('#container').addClass('shadow-left').removeClass('shadow-right');
            } else {
                $('#container').addClass('shadow-right shadow-left');
            }
        }
    });
    $("#scroll-container").trigger("scroll");
});
```

This compares the current `scrollLeft()` value to the maximum available value, and adjusts the classes of the container accordingly.

Additionally, your CSS needed some adjustment. When both `.shadow-left` and `.shadow-right` were applied, then `.shadow-left` would simply *override* the `box-shadow` setting from `.shadow-right`, resulting in only a left shadow. Adding this last statement to the end of your CSS will fix this (which is what I did in the demo):

```
#container.shadow-left.shadow-right {
    box-shadow: inset 7px 0px 10px -7px blue, inset -7px 0px 10px -7px blue;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 7px 0px 10px -7px blue, inset -7px 0px 10px -7px blue;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 7px 0px 10px -7px blue, inset -7px 0px 10px -7px blue;
}
```

**Edit:** I optimized the script a little, since it will be running rapidly, and added a final line that triggers the `scroll` event once when the page loads, so the container has the appropriate shadow from the very beginning.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great Answer..!!

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Shirin_Abdolahi/Y39z8/10/) is what you want,with scroll function in jQuery you know when item is scrolled

```
$('#container').addClass('shadow-right');  


$("#scroll-container").scroll(function(){
    $('#container').addClass('shadow-left');
    x=$("#scroll-container").scrollLeft();
    $("span").text(x);
    if(x==1014){
        x=0;
$('#container').removeClass('shadow-right');

    }
  });
```